# ASP.NET MVC 3 include namespace System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations by default

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, namespaces

This is probably a really silly question, but I can't seem to find an answer for it. In my model classes, I always have to add in a couple of lines of using statements - for example

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
```

Is there any way to have that namespace included automatically in every model class so I don't have to type it in every time?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is [similar to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317901/change-default-namespace-when-creating-class-in-folder-visual-studio) The answer in that question is you have 4 options:

- edit it manually
- live with it
- [change the class template](http://www.rhyous.com/2010/02/17/how-to-modify-the-default-new-class-template-in-visual-studio-2008/) (or export a second class template)
- create the file outside the sub-directory, then drag it in

[see more comments on the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317901/change-default-namespace-when-creating-class-in-folder-visual-studio)

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that you will need to create custom visual studio item template:

[How to create a Visual Studio Item Template](http://zieglers.wordpress.com/2010/06/24/how-to-create-a-visual-studio-item-template/)

Answer (score 0):

This namespace is used for the validation attributes. I tend to write out a property in my class, and add an attribute, e.g. `RequiredAttribute`.

I type `[Required`, and after the `d` Visual Studio puts a little square at the bottom of the line. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> and you'll get a context menu that will add the required `using` statement for you. So you don't ever have to type it out by hand.