# Visual Studio Auto Namespace change

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

In VS2010SP1, i noticed that moving files around in a project from "Root" to a Folder ABC 
changes the namespace from MyNameSpace.X.Y to MyNameSpace.X.Y.ABC

Is there any option/tweak to prevent that ?

Comment: Weird, it shouldn't do that. It should only be doing that during creation of the files.

Comment: It is? THere are a few times that would have been handy, does it change te using clauses in other units as well?

Comment: it does that for the EF4 model files, and changes the [assembly: EdmRelationshipAttribute..] Entity Type FullName in <model>.Designer.cs as well ! Maybe it's an EF special ???

Comment: @Kumar - does it happen if you just move a normal .cs class?  Usually it's addons (like ReSharper) that do things like namespace fixup on file move.

Comment: Don't have resharper but i have EricJ's SQL Server Compact Toolbox Addin

Comment: You could set the namespace provider property of the folder to 'false'

Comment: @DeneB  that's a Resharper property, as noted above, i don't have resharper !

Comment: Kumar, EF derives its suggested namespace for EDMX from the location in the solution structure. You can easily override that by modifying the T4 templates if you use them, otherwise try searching for a specific setting in the EDMX designer.

Answer (score 1):

Entity framework constructs the entity model from an T4 template (ie creates .cs file on the fly) that's why the namespace changed after move. 
If you move simple .cs file, it will not change namespace.

To resolve this issue right click on the folder (in solution explorer) and set property "Namespace provider" into false.

Good luck!