# Visual Studio namespace convention

Tags: c#, namespaces, conventions

I want that all of the files in an assembly will have the assembly name as namespace.

For example, if I create a new class in MyAssembly.SomeFolder - I want that the class defualt namespace will be "MyAssembly" and not "MyAssembly.SomeFolder.

Is there a way to configure this on VS?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change Default Namespace when creating Class in Folder (Visual Studio)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317901/change-default-namespace-when-creating-class-in-folder-visual-studio)

Answer (score 1):

You can change the Visual Studio class template for C# to bypass this.

You may want to look into the Visual Studio templates here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247121.aspx

There are no real settings for this, unless you have ReSharper installed. Then you can set Namespace Provider to false.